# How to pass a stored procedure as a parameter in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure which takes the name of another stored procedure to call on it and with the parameters

However when I try to execute this stored procedure I get an error

What am I doing wrong? From my code below I think I know how to call on a passed stored procedure however I am wondering if it is my syntax that is incorrect.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ADMINDB"."TOOLKIT".LOG_PROCEDURES("P_PROCEDURE_NAME" VARCHAR, "P_PROCEDURE_PARAMETERS" VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT='Inserts into the table PROCEDURE_LOGGING information about the last runned procedure'
EXECUTE AS CALLER 
AS
$$
  var v = P_PROCEDURE_PARAMETERS;
  var v_sqlCode;
  if(P_PROCEDURE_PARAMETERS.length > 0){
    v_sqlCode = `CALL ` + P_PROCEDURE_NAME  + `(` + P_PROCEDURE_PARAMETERS + `)`;
    
  }else{
     return "there was no parameter passed";
   }

  try{
    var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
    var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
  }catch(err){
     errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
     errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
     errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt + v_sqlCode;  
     throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
   }
  return "success!"; 
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ADMINDB"."TOOLKIT".TESTFORLOG("P" VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT='Inserts into the table PROCEDURE_LOGGING information about the last runned procedure'
EXECUTE AS CALLER 
AS 
$$
    var v_sqlCode = 'CREATE TABLE ' + P + `(name varchar)`;
      try{
    var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
    var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
  }catch(err){
     errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
     errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
     errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt + v_sqlCode;  
     throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
   }
  return "success!";
$$;

CALL ADMINDB.TOOLKIT.LOG_PROCEDURES('TESTFORLOG','P');
```

Comment: What output or error do you get when running it?

Comment: "Invalid identifier TESTFORLOG" @Greg Pavlik

Comment: LOG_PROCEDURES is in one schema and TESTFORLOG is in another, perhaps you need to ensure your current database and schema are correct (current context) so that you are resolving the "location" of the procedure correctly.  You could also pass in the fully qualified procedure name.  docs:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/name-resolution.html

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals when passing parameters to the procedure. Within the procedure body, use backticks instead of double quotes, then you don't have to escape single quotes when constructing your SQL statement.

Comment: @MajaF. So I changed the code to follow your suggestions however now I get the error that says "Invalid identifier for P" the passed parameter... Any suggestions please?

Comment: Here is a trick I use when debugging stored procedures: after I construct the SQL statement, in your case after you construct v_sqlCode, just return v_sqlCode (comment out your Snowflake try/catch block). You then receive the SQL statement that will be executed as the procedure output and you can take it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining all of the above comments, here are updated stored procedures which are working when I test here on my dev account.

Notes:

- be careful with the context and use fully qualified names where possible if doing cross schema/database object references
- review your query history when debugging
- backticks are awesome for SQL, I have one sample with and one without in the below
- I like having the SQL in one block (with backticks) and then doing the replace, as illustrated.

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_stacko_1(p1 varchar, p2 varchar)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  EXECUTE AS caller
  AS 
  $$

  var p_procedure_name = P1;
  var p_params = P2;

  if(p_params.length > 0) {
    v_sqlCode = `
      CALL <p_procedure_name>('<p_params>')
      `;
    v_sqlCode = v_sqlCode.replace("<p_procedure_name>", p_procedure_name);
    v_sqlCode = v_sqlCode.replace("<p_params>", p_params);
  }
  else {
    return "there was no parameter passed";
  }

  try {
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: v_sqlCode});
  }
  catch(err){
     errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
     errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
     errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt + v_sqlCode;  
     throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
  }
  return "success!"; 
  $$;

  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_stacko_2(p3 varchar)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  EXECUTE AS caller
  AS 
  $$

  var p_table_name = P3;
  var v_sqlCode = "CREATE TABLE <table_name> (name varchar)";
  v_sqlCode = v_sqlCode.replace("<table_name>", p_table_name);

  try {
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: v_sqlCode});
  }
  catch(err){
     errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
     errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
     errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt + v_sqlCode;  
     throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
  }
  return "success!"; 
  $$;

  CALL sp_stacko_1('sp_stacko_2','P');
  ```